# how to call the category dynamically?

Tags: category, product-list

I have a block setup which will display the products for a category, such as this:

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/working-simple-list.phtml"}}
```

(I'm calling a custom list.phtml in the block so I can control the formatting etc). This block is then called from the category page.

The question is: how can I avoid having to manually enter the category_id? Currently, if I want to call this list.phtml on 5 categories, I need to create 5 unique block calls, setting the ID by hand for each category I want to show it on.

Much cleaner, simpler, would be have it automagically pull the ID, based on which page its called from. Then I would only need one block 'show custom list', and could call it from anywhere.

Any ideas?! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom block type extending `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` specifying the category if using `$this->setCategoryId(..)` method based on your custom logic.

Then you can just replace a type of the block in your `{{block .. }}` call with your new block type and remove `category_id` attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This looks to be a bit beyond my current knowledge. Do you know any tutorial or guide you can point me to that can help with that? Thanks!

Comment: Googling for `magento custom block` returns some promising results.

Comment: OK, thanks - I'll see what I can hack together and report back with a solution for others if/when I manage it :)

Comment: I've found what I think is a simple solution via:
http://workingmagento.blogspot.de/2010/12/magento-display-all-products-in.html#comment-form

Basically, in a category page, I call my customer product list page using this custom layout:

    <reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/working-simple-list.phtml">
    </block>
    </reference>

and it seems to work! On whatever page I put this, it pulls the required products - no need to specify the category ID. Please let me know if there is some downside to this? Thanks!!

Comment: So you put it on a category pages?

Comment: yes - create a category, load the custom layout, which pulls the custom list... seems to work :)